# I'm looking for a part that connects the saddle to the body frame of the bicycle

Tags: parts, saddle

I recently removed the saddle because it was squeaking a lot, then I cleaned the inside and put oil back in, however I couldn't re-attach the bar under the seat to the body frame, then I used this clamp probably in the wrong place and then the hex bolt threaded so I can't get it off.

The bike is a Carrera Subway 2. I should get a new seat anyway, but how can I attach a new saddle and bar thing to the body frame? I don't know what's supposed to screw into here to hold the bar and the saddle in place.

[image: Any help is much appreciated.]

Comment: I forgot to add an image.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/485204327800242177/499197597529931777/image.jpg

Comment: I think the 'bar' you are referring to is the seat post.
Usually seat posts just slide in, and are then held in place by the seat post clamp squeezing the seat tube.

Comment: Do you mean the bolt that you tighten to stop to seat post moving when you sit on the saddle? I'd visit a local municipal dump and see if you can persuade someone to let you check out their dumped bikes!

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on with your seat tube and/or seat post. From the picture, it's hard to see if there's a part of a seat post in the seat tube, or if the picture just shows the seat tube. The top even looks threaded in the pic. But that clamp looks oversized and overtightened from the clearly-visible pinched-looking angle between the two sides.  The clamp's bolt is either binding, bent, or broken given that angle - probably some combination of all three. Get a hacksaw blade, cut the bolt - carefully so you don't mar the frame - and once removed toss the clamp in the trash.

Comment: Can you please add a picture of the saddle and attached seat post? Specifically there it attaches to the frame.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Its a bit unclear what you did or what the problem is. I presume you are having problems reinserting the seat post into the frame. From the above diagram, the seat post slots into the seat tube, and is held in place by the seat post clamp (not labeled).

I also presume hex bolt 'threaded' means you cannot undo the bolt in the seat post clamp. This clamp has to come off to insert the seat post.  My first attempt would be to try to knock it off with a hammer and screw driver by tapping gently around the circumference and 'walking' it up the seat tube. A bit of heat might help. However if the bolt is tight I would not bother.

If that does not work you should be able to cut the bolt with a hack saw blade in the slot, and remove the clamp. An alternate is to drill the bolt head off or cut the clamp itself. New clamps are readily available so do not worry if you damage it.

Once the clamp is off, the seat post should slide fairly easily into the frame, set the height and tighten the new clamp (not too much).

Answer (score 3):

I dare to suggest that the OP has a **suspension seat post** and the squeaks were the sounds of the suspension. From the picture attached I see that the seat post probably never left the seat tube.

It would help us greatly if you add a picture of the other part referred as "the bar under the seat", or even better - all the elements disassembled.

Most likely the suspension seat post needs to be reassembled.

Comment: I think you may be right. I was wondering what the threaded insert on the seat tube was, and it would explain the reference to adding oil. This should be  comment rather than an answer though, unless the OP adds info and it can be expanded.

Comment: Its an excellent thought - I couldn't identify the thread visible, but your suggestion makes sense.   OP needs to find the missing bits, or buy an entirely new seatpost and clamp.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> I cleaned the inside and put oil back in

You should not use liquid oil between the seat post a frame. Use a very thin coating of good quality grease, or better yet a specific bicycle anti-seize compound that will prevent creaks and stop the seat post sticking in the seat tube.

You may also want to check the tightness of the bolts securing the seat post to the saddle rails as these can be a source of creaks too.